Window when starting Windows 11 on Surface 9 pro
A few days ago my Windows 11 on a Surface Tablet 9 pro started showing the following Application/Window right at the start after the unlock screen.
When this window is shown ( for about 20 seconds) everything else (apart from the task manager) seems to be  frozen. No menu at the bottom, gestures don't seem to work and even the two icons on the screen have no effect.
That blue part inside the circle is at a different angle each time so I assume it is meant to be a progress bar even if it is not moving on my screen.
I did not install any new applucations and already kicked out anything from the Startup-settings that does not seem os-related. Win11 has the most current updates installed.
What is it, and especially how to get rid of it?


I assume you are running 23H2 instead of say 22H2?

You have to identify the program using one of the tools that can do that. Process Explorer is one. It has a Target tool that allows you to drag the target over a window and Process Explorer will tell you the information about the processes running that window.

Does this answer your question? How to identify which program has left a portion of its UI floating on my screen?

@music2myear Won't help. This is at the startup and I while this is happening I cannot start any other process. Win seems to be completely frozen

The blue part inside the window is your mouse cursor. Then as John suggested, you need to use AutoRuns to identify the application set to start with Windows.

@Ramhound yes. 23H2.

I assume your local account is connected to a MSA (Microsoft Account)?

@Ramhound thanks for that comment. I fixed the problem like described in the answer, but removing the "auto-login for microsoft apps" also reduced the login-time (BEFORE that now gone white screen significantly) which your comment pointed me to

I finally ended up checking the Task Scheduler, Activating the History there. What helped me finding out the task that took so long. It was the "Sync Language settings". I simply disabled that task and now the problems seem to have gone
